# Java printing squares (unknown characters) alongwith regular text

Tags: java, file, csv

**Code:**

```
public class MainApplication {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

              try{
                  // Open the file that is the first 
                  // command line parameter
                  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data/temp.CSV");
                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
                  String strLine;
                  //Read File Line By Line
                  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                  // Print the content on the console
                  System.out.println (strLine);
                  }
                  //Close the input stream
                  in.close();
                    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                  }
      }
}
```

**CSV file data:**

```
19/1/13 13:58:04    0   1610    0   419 0   0
19/1/13 13:58:05    0.01    1599    66  432 0   1
19/1/13 13:58:06    0.02    1603    47  423 0   2
19/1/13 13:58:07    0.03    1602    26  413 0   3
19/1/13 13:58:08    0.04    1605    130 412 0   4
```

**Output:**

[image: Error screen]

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-16LE"));
```

Instead of

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. That is working. I tried UTF-8 but it was not working.

Comment: Don't use string literals for character sets. Instead use `StandardCharsets` when possible. So you'd replace `"UTF-16LE"` with `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE`.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

with

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

Replace `"UTF-8"` with the encoding of your `.csv` file.

Using this constructor of the `InputStreamReader` handles your input correct according to the given charset. If you don't specify the charset and have *strange* output, it is an indicator that the file is encoded in an encoding different than your systems default.

Also, you can get rid of the `DataInputStream` and write

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream, "UTF-16"));
```

**EDIT** *Thanks Henry for pointing out the following:*

Looking at your output, every character seems to be encoded using 2 Bytes. This indicates it's encoding is UTF-16. You should use `"UTF-16"` in the constrcutor accordingly.

Comment: The encoding used is probably UTF-16

Comment: Looking at the output, it is some 16 bit encoding (the correct characters are intermixed with an unknown one, likely a \000)